# Why does stripslashes not return the data without a slash?

Tags: php

When you press login on my site, the script uses `mysqli_real_escape_string` and than process the login.

When you are for example at the homepage and you press the login button there, the site goes to this file. if everything goes well, you will be redirected to the begin page but when something goes wrong, you will stay at this page and see a form. The form contains the data you entered before your pressed login. THAT data contains a slash at the end.

I want to remove the slashes by using `stripslashes` so I created a function called `slash` to remove them but when you enter the wrong things I still see the slashes.

```
//the slash function is placed in a previous loaded file
function slash($username, $password){
     $password =  stripslashes($password);
     $username =  stripslashes($username);
     return $username;
     return $password;
}

    if(empty($_POST === false)){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //check if the fields are empty
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
    //check if the username exists
    }else if(user_exists($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username';
        slash($username, $password);
    //check if the username is active
    }else if(user_active($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account';
        slash($username, $password);
    //if none of the previous checks are false, log in
    }else{
        $login = login($username, $password);
        //if username or password is incorrect, display error
        if($login === false){
            $errors[] = 'That username or password combination is incorrect';
            slash($username, $password);
        //if everthing is fine, log in
        }else{
            //set the user session
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            //redirect user to home
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/error_login.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'templates/menu/menu.php';
?>
<div class="error_login">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <div id="login">
                username:<br>
                <input type="text" name="username" value=<?php echo $username; ?>/><br><br>

                password:<br>
                <input type="password" name="password" value=<?php echo $password; ?>/><br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Log In"/><br><br>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        error_output($errors);
                    ?>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <?php
        include 'templates/footer/footer.php';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**

```
input:
username: test
password:
```

The input is invalid like your see because there is no password so the site will reshow a form with the userinput + an added slash

```
output: 
username: test/ 
password: ●
```

Comment: Your function has 2 `return` statements. `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: You don't actually say where / at what point you're looking and seeing the slashes/

Comment: Can we see the form's HTML code?

Comment: @caCtus I added the code and explained the question much better

Comment: Add some double-quotes to your `value` attributes: `value="<?php echo $password; ?>"`. Same with username.

Comment: @caCtus Is that a secure way because you are displaying the userdata immediately

Comment: It's not a secure or unsecure issue. It's how HTML works. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @caCtus yes but all tutorials say you have to be carefull to prevent sql-injection and with this way you are displaying the user data immediately

Comment: There is no SQL injection issue when you display a username between double-quotes in an HTML attribute. You're mixing different things here...

Comment: Your issue is not about removing that slash, but not having it at first. By writing correct HTML code you won't have that slash.

Comment: Well thank you for your help, it works now. So was php adding that / because I did not output the result between "" ? And a small other question: Why does my question has no upvotes? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: PHP didn't add any slash. The slash was in the HTML because your attribute wasn't correctly wrapped in double quotes, so in a few words it did its best to understand.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/stripslashes. It removes BACKSLASHES (e.g. ``\``), not forward slashes (`/`). It will also remove only ONE layer of backslashes.

Comment: @caCtus but than I don't understand where `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for because I thought that function added the slash

Comment: Yeah `value=<?php echo $username; ?>/>` and `value=<?php echo $password; ?>/>` I figured as much.

Comment: @MarcB That makes sense to.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes special characters before using your variables in a SQL statement. You have to use it before using your variables in a SQL statement, not anywhere else. (I think there's nothing to do with your original question though, you should read tutorials that explain what they are making you do. If you understand what you are doing, you will have less errors like this one. :) )

Comment: I'd do away with that `slash()` function and use prepared statements. Your code will be much smaller too and safer. Plus, hoping you are using a modern-day hashing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value=<?php echo $username; ?>/>
```

You missed the double-quotes to the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
```

This is the same for password.